# Function name and object name conflict

Tags: r, function, httr

So I am using `modify_url` function in the `httr` package to construct a correct URL for my API call. Below is what I try to do:

```
# url <- "url of api call"
query <- list(limit = 100, id = id, select = all)
new_URL <- modify_url(url, query = query)
```

In the API call, I need to include the parameter `select=all`. However, since I have loaded the `dplyr` package, the name `select` has been occupied by the `select` function and the object name conflict occurs here.

Ideally, I would like to have the list `query` as below:

```
query

$limit
[1] 100

$id
[1] "id"

$select
[1] "all"
```

But it is now:

```
query
$limit
[1] 100

$id
[1] "id"

$select
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("all")
```

Is there any way to work around this? Many thanks!

Comment: Because you are calling unquoted version where `all` is a function

Comment: `"all"` is a string, `all` is a function from base R. `select` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @akrun Yeah, thats my guess at first. I try to use `enquo()` to solve that, but it does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Use a string: `"all"`

Comment: @Chuan `enquo` works from within a function.  Not clear how the input process works.  If it is `query <- list(limit = 100, id = "id", select = "all")`, it would work but I think these are UI supplied values?

Comment: oh.. my mistake. I used `ls()` to check, but didn't see the `all` function. Very weird. I change to `"all"` and it seems work now. Thanks!

Comment: `ls()` only shows you user-defined object by default, not built-in functions or functions loaded from packages.

Comment: @Gregor  thank you! Just realize `all` is a base function (never used it before). How stupid I am. thank you for help out.

Comment: Voting to close as typo... not really generalizable problem, just missing quotes around a string.